# React native react-navigation createBottomTabNavigator do not show icons

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

I would like to remove the icons from the Bottom Tab Navigator, I've tried using the `tabBarShowIcon` flag with both `true` and `false` but it doesn't seem to work.

Editor tells me that this property doesn't exist.

Can you tell me where I'm wrong?

```js
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.12",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.6",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.7.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.20.0",
    "react-native-super-grid": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^12.0.2"
  }
```

```js
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Home"
        screenOptions={{
          tabBarShowIcon: false,// true
        }}>
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Home"
          children={(navigation) => <HomeScreen navigation={navigation} type={0} />}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: `screenOptions={{tabBarIconStyle: { display: "none" }}}` Doesn't this work?

Comment: @KrishanMadushanka: I already tried: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BljeL.png

As you can see the image is not visible, but it seems that the space of the icon remains.

Comment: Try setting `height:0` also

Comment: @KrishanMadushanka: Inside screenOptions?

Comment: yes `screenOptions={{tabBarIconStyle: { display: "none",height:0 }}}`

Comment: @KrishanMadushanka: It doesn't work, you can see it too: https://snack.expo.dev/TpWZHrRU-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
screenOptions={{ tabBarLabelPosition: "beside-icon",tabBarIconStyle: { display: "none" }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tabBarIcon` option inside the `screenOptions` prop of `Tab.Navigator`

```js
<Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarIcon: (props)=>null,
}}>
```